# C++ “+” (plus) sign in front of class instance

Tags: c++, c++17

Helllo,
I’m reading the following code from Mach7 (which looks great btw, I wonder why c++17 didn’t adopt it but that’s off topic...)

```
bool operator==(const Term& left, const Term& right)
{
    //std::clog << "(" << left << ',' << right << ')' << std::endl;
    var<std::string> s;
    //var<const Var&>  v;
    var<const Term&> v,t,f;

    Match(left,right)
    {
    Case(C<Var>(s),     C<Var>(+s)     ) return true;
    Case(C<Abs>(&v,&t), C<Abs>(&+v,&+t)) return true;
    Case(C<App>(&f,&t), C<App>(&+f,&+t)) return true;
    Otherwise()                          return false;
    }
    EndMatch

    return false; // To prevent all control path warning
}
```

(see [here](https://github.com/solodon4/Mach7/blob/master/code/test/time/lambda.cpp#L127-L144))

What does “+s” mean in the second match case? Semantically it should mean, “make another like s by calling the constructor” but I have never seen this syntax.

Comment: Please include the code in question here, in your question, so that it's still useful even if your link goes stale.

Comment: Does `s` over load the `operator+()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After poking around (as no class of that type implements `unary operator +`, I was surprised to find out) it seems they create a `unary +` operator that they include from `equivalence.hpp`.

TL;DR, they have something like the following in the global namespace:

```
template <typename T>
inline auto operator+(T&& t) noexcept { return true; }
```

except theirs actually does something. :)

Comment: What is this style of operator overloading on a template called and how can I learn more?